# jQuery and Rails ajax request and response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Trying the basic stuff,

request with data and response with data and print it with jQuery and Rails

This is the front code.

```
$("#internal_btn").click(function() {
            //window.alert("clicked internal btn!");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/room/test",
                //data: "{'data1':'" + value1+ "', 'data2':'" + value2+ "', 'data3':'" + value3+ "'}",
                data: {name:"ravi",age:"31"},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                //do somthing here
                    window.alert("success!!");
                },
                error: function (){
                    window.alert("something wrong!");
                }
            });
        });
```

in here, if the user clicks internal_btn this event happens and goes to the servide

room/test action.

ok this is fine. But I'm not sure how to send the data.

If i run this, i have an error like this.

```
MultiJson::LoadError

795: unexpected token at 'name=ravi&age=31'
```

Can i know what the problem is?

Also, is there are good example with this request and response with json format?

I googled a lot, but not satisfied with the result :(

Comment: can you show us your controller action that respond json data

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't make the controller action. First i'm trying to request to the controller and get the pararmeters from the front.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `stringify` your `data` or use `GET method` like,

```
data : JSON.stringify({name:"ravi",age:"31"}),
```

**Full Code**,

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",// GET in place of POST
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "/room/test",
     data : JSON.stringify({name:"ravi",age:"31"}),
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (result) {
        //do somthing here
        window.alert("success!!");
     },
     error: function (){
        window.alert("something wrong!");
     }
});
```

Comment: Thannks, i dont' know why, but i changed the type to "GET" and now it works. :)

Comment: To help others: I think the colleague has incorrect routes. Because of this, the code works when change from POST to GET.